# How can i disable internet connectivity for specific apps in android through my app?

Tags: android

How can i disable INTERNET connectivity for specific application in android through my application ? Or get the path of usage data application and find specific application to restrict the INTERNET access. On the other hand,i want selected application to get access from INTERNET and some selected applications are running in background like hike but not use my data. ? is this possible ?

if possible,please help me.

some methods are found,but this is not the proper way to doing this.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device